# I am trying to highlight the output with mark tag but it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show my output highlighted with yellow color, but it's not highlighted...
Here's my part of code where I got values and calculated the result as `si` and printed after "You will recieve an amount of" as highlighted with yellow.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("principal").value;
var r = document.getElementById("rate").value;
var n = document.getElementById("years").value;
var si = parseInt((p * n * r) / 100);
document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = si + ",";
document.getElementById('num00').innerHTML = "You will recieve an amount of ";
```

```css
mark {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="num00"></div><br>
<div id="num"><mark></mark></div>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the inputs such as principal, rate and years in your HTML code ? Can you make a snippet of your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe is due to this line:

```
document.getElementById ('num').innerHTML = si+",";
```

This replaces the existing `innerHTML` of the selected element with the created HTML; so the `<mark>` element no longer exists.

Instead, I'd suggest:

```
document.querySelector('#num mark').textContent = si+",";
```

Which uses CSS selector syntax to find the `<mark>` element within an element whose `id` is "num".

```js
const calculate = () => {
  let p = parseInt(document.getElementById("principal").value),
      r = parseInt(document.getElementById("rate").value),
      n = parseInt(document.getElementById("years").value),
      si = parseInt((p * n * r) / 100);

  document.querySelector('#num mark').textContent = si + ",";
  document.getElementById('num00').innerHTML = "You will recieve an amount of ";
  },
  button = document.querySelector('button');
  
  button.addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

```css
mark {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
label {
display: flex;
width: 60%;
justify-content: space-between;
margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Set values</legend>
  <label>Principal
  <input type="number" min="40" max="300" step="1" id="principal" />
  </label>
  <label>Rate
  <input type="number" min="0.3" max="2" step="1" id="rate" />
  </label>
  <label>Years
  <input type="number" min="2" max="40" step="1" id="years" />
  </label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <button type="button" id="test">Get quote</button>
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="num00"></div><br>
<div id="num"><mark></mark></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the support I will try this solution.

Comment: I have nt used any form or field set tags in my code, Is it important? Or a cause of the problem?

Comment: No, it's entirely irrelevant; I used them because they're semantically correct in most cases and afford meaning to the content; this is useful for those people using the web with non-visual cues.

Comment: Thanks bro that worked well. I cant upvote you because i need more reputation points for that. Sorry about it. Once again thanks for the explanations.

Comment: That’s no problem, @Mohd, upvotes and acceptance aren’t obligatory (though much appreciated of course). If this answer solved the problem then consider accepting the answer (clicking the check-mark beside the answer), but consider waiting a while as better answers may be offered by others.